# How to return a value from a range if cell contains that value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list of Names (First and Surname) in A:A. I also have a range called 'Surnames'. How can I apply a formula so that B:B returns the surname only of A:A if that name is found in the range 'Surnames'.

I other words, I want to check a cell in A1, if part of this cell value contains a name listed in my range of surnames, return the surname that A1 include in B1.

I hope this makes sense, and thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

Make a copy of Range A:A and paste it in range C:C and use Text to columns function for range C:C. This will separate First names and Last names in to two ranges C:C (First Names) & D:D (Last Names).
Get rid of extra spaces in both the columns C & D by using clean function

Step 2

Now use vlookup in range E:E.  E.g. E1 =VLookup(D1,B:B,1,FALSE).  This will return the surname if it matches with your surname range in B:B or else returns #N/A (meaning not available).

Hope this helps